# Angular 2 Validator errors

Tags: angular, forms, reactive

I'm trying to verify the password is long enough but it sends this error.
I'm verifying the same way for my emails and I don't have any problems ..

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.registerForm = this.fb.group({
       username: ['', Validators.required],
       email: ['', [Validators.required,
           Validators.pattern('[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$')]],
        password: ['', Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)],
        confirmpwd: ['', Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)],
        birthday: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }

ERROR Error: Expected validator to return Promise or Observable.

<div *ngIf="password.invalid && password.touched">
          <p *ngIf="password.errors?.required">
               Choose a password
          </p>
          <p *ngIf="password.errors?.minlength">
               The password is too short
          </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Add your implementation of the ReactiveForm as well. Looks like you used a Synchronous Custom Validator in place of an Async Validator.

Comment: Could you show more of the code? How is your validation set up? Are you using template driven or reactive forms?

Comment: @DeborahK my validation setup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
password: ['', Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)],
```

To this:

```
password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)]],
```

Add the validators to an array.

- The first element in the array is the default.
- The second element of the array is a single validator OR an array of validators.
- The third element of the array is a single async validator or an array of async validators.

So the second validator you listed is being handled as an async validator.

You'll need to make this change to the other formControls as well. (The email is actually correct.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. i see now why it didn't work.

Comment: If this resolved your issue, please mark it as your answer to close this question. Thanks!